# I'd like to scan the metasploitable2 VM with zap api scan (the docker one) using a context file but it seems the authentication doesn't work

Tags: docker, api, authentication, zap

I am working on scan automatisation and trying it on metasploitable2 VM using the following command:

*docker container run --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk --name container01 owasp/zap2docker-stable:latest zap-api-scan.py -g gen.conf -t http://192.168.56.104/ -f openapi -d -n fContext.context -U admin -r reporAdmin-test.html*

My context file contains the following info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration>
    <context>
        <name>Default context</name>
        <desc/>
        <inscope>true</inscope>
        <incregexes>http://192.168.56.104/</incregexes>
        <tech>

....

<authentication>
            <type>2</type>
            <strategy>EACH_RESP</strategy>
            <pollurl/>
            <polldata/>
            <pollheaders/>
            <pollfreq>60</pollfreq>
            <pollunits>REQUESTS</pollunits>
            <loggedout>Login failed</loggedout>
            <form>
                <loginurl>http://192.168.56.104/dvwa/</loginurl>
                <loginbody>username={%username%}&amp;password={%password%}</loginbody>
                <loginpageurl>http://192.168.56.104/dvwa/login.php</loginpageurl>
            </form>
        </authentication>
        <users>
            <user>2;true;YWRtaW4=;2;YWRtaW4=~cGFzc3dvcmQ=~</user>
            <user>3;true;dXNlcg==;2;dXNlcg==~dXNlcg==~</user>
            <user>4;true;dXNlcnA=;2;dXNlcg==~cGFzc3dvcmQ=~</user>
        </users>
        <forceduser>2</forceduser>
```

The context file has been generated via the UI of zap.

There's the right user and password set (admin & password) for the page http://192.168.56.104/dvwa/login.php and in the command I specify I that I want to use the user admin.

I get the following report:
[summary screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B11Ry.png)
I get the same without using -U admin parameter, So I guess I missed something about authentication but I can't figure what it is.

The problem is that I have a small report, not including all the page of dvwa (SQL injection pages, XSS vulnerable pages etc.)
[The following pages should also be scaned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fFCF.png)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I dont have the answer but I can point you at some resources that should help.
Handling authentication is hard :/ 
We do have a new guide for that in ZAP but it is WIP :/ https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/authentication/
But also have a look at the videos on https://www.zaproxy.org/videos-list/ - just search for "auth".
Note that questions about ZAP should be answered more quickly on the ZAP User Group: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Comment: Thanks I'll look at all of that and come back into ZAP users group if I'm still blocked !

Comment: Your include Regex isn't a Regex, it's a literal single URL.  Is this about metasploitable or DVWA because they're not the same. For DVWA see: https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/details/setting-up-zap-to-test-dvwa/